# Supremum of lower bounds is a lower bound.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary set that is bounded from below and let $B$ be the set of lower bounds of $A$. I'm trying to prove that $\sup{B} = \inf{A}$ by appealing to the *definition* of $\inf$: (i) $\sup{B}$ is a lower bound of $A$ and (ii) $\sup{B}$ is larger than any lower bound $A$.

I have proved (ii) but I am having difficulty proving (i). If $\sup{B} \in B$ then I know that it is a lower bound of $A$ by the way I have defined $B$. However it is not guaranteed that the supremum of a set will be an element of the set. How can I prove that $\sup{B}$ is a lower bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that there exists $a\in A$ with $a<\sup(B)$. By definition of supremum, we have $B\cap (\sup(B)-\varepsilon,\sup(B)]\neq\varnothing$ for each $\varepsilon>0$. So take $b\in B\cap (a,\sup(B)]$ using $\varepsilon=\sup(B)-a>0$. I'll leave it to you to finish.

Comment: I think I understand. If I use $\sup{B} - \varepsilon < b \leq \sup{B}$ and then substitute $\varepsilon$ in I'll get a contradiction right? And then that will prove that $\sup{B} \leq a$ for all $a \in A$ and hence it it's a lower bound?

Comment: Yeah the idea is to get a contradiction here to get $\sup(B)\let A$.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggested answer

We should consider two cases

Case One: $\sup (B) \ge a $ where $a \in A$

Cases Two: $\sup (B) < a $ where $a \in A$

From case One, we have $$\inf (A)-\varepsilon <a\le\sup (B) \Rightarrow \inf (A) <\sup (B)+\varepsilon \Rightarrow \inf(A) \le \sup (B) $$

From cases two, we have $$\sup (B)<a<\inf(A)+\varepsilon \Rightarrow \sup (B)<\inf (A) +\varepsilon \Rightarrow \sup (B) \le \inf (A) $$

Hence, from the two cases we have $$\sup (B) = \inf (A) $$